# Rails - partial with different statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

in my app I have partial

```
@users.each do |user|
  = user.name
  = user.avatar
  = user.uid
```

But in different views I should call it with statements

```
 - if user.sex == 1
   = user.name
   = user.avatar
   = user.uid
```

Or

```
- if user.sex == 2
   = user.name
   = user.avatar
   = user.uid
```

How can I render partial with different statements in views?

Thanks!

Comment: what does `statements` mean here??

Comment: I mean conditional statement if else

Comment: Perhaps [`local variables`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) would be apt here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to have the user.each part outside of the partial - like this:

in your 'main' view:

```
@users.each do |user|
  if user.sex == 1
    render 'female_partial', [locals]
  elsif user.sex == 2
    render 'male_partial', [locals]
  else 
    render 'no_gender_partial', [locals]
  end
end
```

and in each partial render what you need to.  Just curious, though - there doesn't seem to be any difference between what you're rendering conditionally?  If you say exactly what you want to do, you'll probably get a better answer.